# Java - Replace single quote without affecting multi single quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

Is it possible to replace a single quote ' without affecting multi-single quotes (e.g. ''').

For example, I want to replace ' with '''

```
GIVEN --> EXPECT
-------------------------------------------
"text" --> "text"
"long'text" --> "long'''text"
"long'long''text" --> "long'''long''text" 
"long'long'''text" --> "long'''long'''text" 
"long'long'text" --> "long'''long'''text"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For matching use this look-around based regex:

```
(?<!')'(?!')
```

and replace it by:

```
'''
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dI2gC3/1)

`(?<!')'(?!')` matches a single quote if is not followed and preceded by a single quote.